# Execute object method in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to call an method from an object in jsp.

I have an servlet which passes an object to a jsp page. On this page I want to execute the `getHtml()` method. How do I accomplish this?

*Servlet*

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    response.setAttribute(myObject, "myObject");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

*MyClass*

```
public class MyClass {
    public String getHtml() {
        return "<p>Hello World</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: in index.jsp just get it by `(MyClass)request.getAttribute("myObject").getHtml();` and cast it to the object MyClass

Comment: You should not invoke methods or logic in general from the view layer. It should be better to place the html in the request instead of the object that can get what you need.

Comment: that's a very good point. I'd like to do so. But there is one problem. I have several `http-servlet` classes, one for each action. How do I pass a created object from on to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```
<div>${myObject.getHtml()}</div>
```

As it is a property and with the *get* prefix you may also do:

```
<div>${myObject.html}</div>
```

Or this way to scape HTML characters to avoid cross-site scripting:

```
<div><c:out value="${myObject.hHtml}"/></div>
```

All this ways assume that those methods return a String. If you need a piece of dynamic HTML it is OK. If you are doing some business logic in JSP it would be looked as a potencial bad practice. Try to put as much logic as possible in the controller or service and get the results preprocessed as properties or use jsp tags. At some point the html of the jsp will need to change or you would have used html instead.